# Input value doesn't show inside bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a directive to display a bootstrap's popover where user can update some value. The problem is that my value is not visible as an input's value (it's bind, I can edit it). Same value is visible inside the popover just next to the input.

*HTML*

```
<div custom-popover popover-html="<div><span>{{costPrice}}</span><input type='text' ng-model='costPrice' /></div>"></div>
```

*JS*

```
$(elem).popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            html: true,
            content: () => {
                var content = $compile(attr.popoverHtml)(scope);
                return content;
            },
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8M6Vzil5t9oPW190XGKp?p=preview)**

It's of course some piece of whole project only, but it shows the issue. Any idea of how to make this value visible inside the input?

Comment: why u use jquery plugins? ..

Comment: Do you just want to add `value='{{costPrice}}'` to the `input`?

Comment: so your pop over is not updating the value?

Comment: @DavidG not really. Value should be set there by this ng-model this works in "normal" scenario, and doesn't work only in this popover.

Comment: @YashGanatra It updating the value, but at the beginning when popover pops up value is not displayed in input. It's well visible in example.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured out what's the issue.
You are using jquery for pop-over as it's not a good practice to use the jquery code with angular
Here in your case you are using angular and what ng-model does is it continuously watch on the element value and if it's change it calls the digest cycle to update all the values as per the model and vice versa.
So, as you have given the angular code to jquery content function it can cause the angular to stop watching for `costPrice` which you can see in popover if you implement it by ui-bootstrap popover or any other angular third party popovers then you can see the effects. Here is the code for that,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">

        <button style="margin:70px;" uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-placement="bottom-right" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}"
            type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
            <div>{{dynamicPopover.content}}</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Popup Title:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.content" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </script>
        <script>
            angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
            angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
                $scope.dynamicPopover = {
                    content: 'Hello, World!',
                    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
                    title: 'Title'
                };
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So as I said you gave the html with angular code to jquery to handle it and jquery cant handle the angular code so you get the error.
Hopefully this will help :)